# creating custom design for control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I want to create my custom design for standart controls in WPF. Like this [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW7ik.png)

With my press animation, focus animation and so on. But to the rest of the properties, events were like a normal button. Similarly, for other controls.

What can i use for it? Is it will hard to inject my control in WPF? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think no, because there no change of shape of button and animation

Comment: You should really read about [WPF styles and Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.100).aspx)